# Load YAML from file in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following structure:

```
/Jenkinsfile/script2.groovy
/Jenkinsfile/pipeline2.yaml
script1.groovy
pipeline1.yaml
```

There's a reference in script1 to the pipeline using:

```
yamlFile "pipeline1.yml"
```

or

```
yamlFile "./Jenkinsfiles/pipeline2.yaml"
```

And works fine. I'm trying to use the same pipeline file on script2 but can't make it work.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud "xxxx"
            yamlFile "pipeline.yml"
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

**Note:** pipeline1 and pieline2 are the same files just showing different locations.

Answer (score 1):

Given the directory structure you mentioned:

```sh
.
├── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── pipeline2.yaml
│   └── script2.groovy
├── pipeline1.yaml
└── script1.groovy
```

The following files can be read from within their parent directory as follows:

**For script1** ran from `./`

- `groovy ./script1.groovy` is able to read both `./pipeline1.yaml` and `./Jenkinsfile/pipeline2.yaml`

**For Script2** ran from `./`

- `groovy ./Jenkinsfile/script2.groovy` is able to read `./pipeline1.yaml`, since its in the same directory the file `./Jenkinsfile/script2.groovy` is **being run from** i.e. `./`
- `groovy ./Jenkinsfile/script2.groovy` is able to read `./Jenkinfile/pipeline2.yaml` also because the path is relative.

---

I think you could possibly simplify this by just having the files reside in one directory. And also using the syntax `readYaml(file: './nameOfFile.yaml')` [readyaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) section.

```
.
├── pipeline1.yaml
├── script1.groovy
├── pipeline2.yaml
└── script2.groovy
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, maybe something in how Jenkins runs the scripts?